# How to write function similar to `echo` in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm trying to write wrapper for `echo` the code below doesn't work, [playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2M5g)

```
import sequtils, strutils, sugar

proc p*(args: varargs[typed, `$`]): void =
  echo args.map((v) => $v).join(" ")
```

Error:

```
/usercode/in.nim(3, 8) Error: invalid type: 'typed' in this context: 'proc (args: varargs[typed])' for proc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import sequtils, strutils, sugar

proc p*(args: varargs[string, `$`]): void =
  echo args.join(" ")
```

`varargs` accepts type *to be converted to* as first argument, so your code is almost correct, but you need to replace `typed` with `string`, and then the function call would be equivalent to `p([$arg1, $arg2])` basically.

Nim by example for `varargs` - [link](https://nim-by-example.github.io/varargs/)

Comment: You didn't mention that `echo` can accept `varargs[typed]` because it's a compiler magic.

Comment: since conversion to string is already done by `varargs[string, $]` you can also drop the `map`.